# Echo specific character range from multiple filenames within a directory in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, echo

For a given set of files ending in `.bam` within `/a/given/path/` I would like to echo a specific string of characters that is variable in length. I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
for dir in /a/given/path/*.bam; do echo ${dir##path/%%.bam}; done
```

The intention is to echo the bam filenames (from `path/` onwards) without the .bam extension, but it just echoes the entire path. If I change to:

```
for dir in /a/given/path/*.bam; do echo ${dir%%.bam}; done
```

it will echo

```
/a/given/path/filename1
/a/given/path/filename22
```

Ideally I will be able to echo the filename only even for filenames of various lengths (which is preventing me from using `echo ${dir:15:9}`, for example).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to do this:

```
for dir in /a/given/path/*.bam; do dir="${dir##*/}"; echo "${dir%.bam}"; done
```

(two-step substitution) or

```
( cd /a/given/path && for dir in *.bam; do echo "${dir%.bam}"; done )
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Unix has commands "dirname" and "basename" that can be combined to do what (I think) you are asking for.

```
for f in "/a/given/path"/*.bam;do
  echo $(basename "$(dirname "$f")")/$(basename "$f" .bam);done
```

All the double-quotes are to handle possible spaces in path- and filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Use `basename` to get the filename and then `cut` to discard `.bam`

`for dir in /a/given/path/*.bam; do basename $dir | cut -f 1 -d .; done`